# Destroying the instance that instantiated the prefab

Tags: c#, unity

What I have so far:

A `fuel` that has Fuel script attached to it.
The `fuel` prefab is first instantiated from another script in its Start() method.

**problem:**
The `Fuel` script is such that it results in instantiation of prefab `fuel` repeatedly at some intervals of time and keeps destroying the earlier ones.
But

the prefab that was instantiated from the other script stays there always. I want this prefab to be destroyed as well(or atleast made invisible) while the process of instantiation and destruction of of `fuel` prefabs continues to go on.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't instantiate from the Fuel script. I mean, obviously if you don't want a second copy of the object then don't *make* a second copy of the object.

You say "the fuel prefab is first instantiated from another script"; so handle *all* the instantiating and destroying in that script, not just the first time.